# What does int[] point to?

Tags: java

Or what is its value exactly?

This pertains to a question about this code:

```
private static int[] x;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.print(x[0]);
   }
```

Which does not compile (obviously).

Comment: Uh...It compiles fine.

Comment: I meant it throws a runtime exception.

Comment: The value of `x` in your `main` method is `null`. Trying to dereference it in order to access the element at index `0` causes a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: [Here's the official tutorial on Arrays.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of x is `null`.

It gives a `NullPointerException` when you do:

```
System.out.print(x[0]);
```